# Flutter IOC using model name as string like laravel

Tags: laravel, flutter, dart, inversion-of-control

I want to use IOC in Flutter/Dart using model name in string format like below

```
namespace My;

class NewClass {

    function __construct($id, $title) 
    {
        $this->id    = $id;
        $this->title = $title;
    }
}


$newClass = App::make('My\NewClass', [1, 'test']);
```

the above is how IOC can be used in laravel. Here we are dynamically using the model name or namespace ,'My\NewClass', as a string.